# Django/Wagtail - Dynamically generate choices based on uploaded document

Tags: django, django-forms, wagtail

I am trying to implement a Chart Block in Wagtail where a user can upload a spreadsheet via the DocumentChooserPanel and then a chart is generated based on the data in that spreadsheet.

I currently have it functioning, but the user must explicitly specify the variable they want the chart to be based off of:

```
class ChartBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    data_file = DocumentChooserBlock()
    primary_variable = blocks.CharBlock(required=True,max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        template = 'dataviz/blocks/Chart.html'
        icon = 'cogs'
        label = 'Chart'
```

I was wondering if there is any way to have the primary_variable field dynamically populated with the column headers from the spreadsheet uploaded and stored in Documents - so that the user would be able to choose from a list of available variables instead of having to remember what a variable was called.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be easy to achieve with a vanilla implementation of Wagtail.

The page edit form is generated on page load, including the population of choice lists. I'm pretty sure that the same is true of choice lists in StreamField blocks, that they are populated as the block is added.

The code for this hangs between wagtailadmin.edit_handlers, wagtailadmin.views.pages and wagtailcore.blocks. It would be a pretty complex customisation.

Another possible route for investigation would be using the [insert_editor_js](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.3.1/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-js) hook to update the primary_variable field once a document was uploaded. However, I'm not sure you'll find a dependable ID to hang an event listener off of.

However, you will soon be able to custom validate the submitted page. A [PR has just been submitted](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/pull/1867#issue-113489776) to allow this custom validation. That should reduce the amount of user error when adding the primary_variable.

This feature should be available in Wagtail 1.4, which I believe is due for release pretty soon.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The [PR Chris mentions above](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/pull/1867) has been merged, so custom validation will certainly be available in Wagtail 1.4. A release candidate should be available in the next few days.